# Using Alias in Like Query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a Query "namePrefix + ' ' + nameFirstname + ' ' + nameSurname AS salName".
How can I use it in Store Procedure Like Query?

Comment: can u be more specific? or ca n u rephrase your question? what specific engine used? MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: can you show your full query!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  select a.salName from (
      select namePrefix || ' ' || nameFirstname || ' ' || nameSurname salName 
      from table1) a
  where a.salName  like `%partialName%`;
```

For stored proc, if `l_full_name_search` represents the variable holding search string, you may write the query as:

```
  select a.salName from (
         select namePrefix || ' ' || nameFirstname || ' ' || nameSurname salName 
         from table1) a
   where a.salName  like '%'||l_full_name_search||'%';
```

Comment: How can I use it in Stored Procedure? Thanks